# wdio-video-reporter - ERROR @wdio/runner: Error: Some reporters are still unsynced: Video

Tags: webdriver-io, wdio

1. I added `const video = require('wdio-video-reporter');` to `wdio.conf.js`
2. I added to wdio.conf.js

```
capabilities: [
    {
      ...
      "appium:deviceType": "phone",
      "browserVersion": "73.0-phone-1",
      ...
    },
],
reporters: [
    [
      'cucumberjs-json',
      {
        jsonFolder: './results/report/json/',
        language: 'en',
      },
    ],
    [
      video,
      {
        saveAllVideos: true,
        videoSlowdownMultiplier: 1,
        outputDir: './results/report/',
        maxTestNameCharacters: 100,
      },
    ],
  ],
```

But I got this error. What should I do next? Can I add wdio-video-report to wdio-cucumberjs-json-reporter and multiple-cucumber-html-reporter?

Thanks

[image: error log]

Comment: Is the app build you provide able to start ? I got this when the build is not good.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the one of the configuration of your cucumber feature file is not correct  I had the same that the header was not in line with the testdata

Once that was fixed the issue was gone, and I did not have this error anymore  for this feature file

Comment: Can you please, provide more information about what was missing? I am having a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case my feature file was missing any scenarios and thus this error occurred.

After adding scenarios for the background it worked properly.

Here is some gherkin references for the feature file syntax: https://cucumber.io/docs/gherkin/reference/